# Rows inside a table grow to use all available height

Tags: html, css

I am having troubles trying to make this work the way I want.
I have a table with a fixed height. And all *tr* I put inside this table grow in height to use all available table's height, although *tr* have a specific height
For example my table has *widht: 1000px* and if I only have 1 row, this row will be 1000px high, if I have 2 rows, each one will be 500px high

Here is a simple fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/6wfbohbh/2/

```
table { height:1000px; }
tr {height: 100px; }
```

How can I have the *tr* use their heights and not be relative to the tables height?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do not set height unless you need it :

example shrinking header to the height it needs to hold content and let other rows to spray.

```css
table {
  height:400px;/* to see demo */
  float:left; 
  border:solid red 1px;
  }
/* see tds */

td {border:solid;}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr style="height:1%">
      <td>English</td>
      <td>Spanish</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Hello</td>
      <td>Hola</td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>Bye</td>
      <td>Adios</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr style="height:1%">
      <td>English</td>
      <td>Spanish</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Hello</td>
      <td>Hola</td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>Bye</td>
      <td>Adios</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Hello</td>
      <td>Hola</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table><table>
  <thead>
    <tr >
      <td>no height given on thead tr</td>
      <td>Spanish</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Hello</td>
      <td>Hola</td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>Bye</td>
      <td>Adios</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

that's about what you can do if td's content is even ...

---

If you want to keep tr's to that 100px height even there is not enough to keep them, then use a pseudo to fake last row:

```css
tbody:after {
  content:'';
  display:table-row;
  height:100%;
  }
```

```html
<table style="height:1000px;">
  <thead>
    <tr style="1%">
      <td>English</td>
      <td>Spanish</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr style="height: 100px;">
      <td>Hello</td>
      <td>Hola</td>
    </tr>
     <tr style="height: 100px;">
      <td>Bye</td>
      <td>Adios</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks, but i need the height to be that way, mainly because of the design. Imagine the background have to be 'covered' like in this fiddle, if I dont put the height, the red color will be seen https://jsfiddle.net/6wfbohbh/9/

Comment: @azibi ?? what is that red color about ? , i guess i need that you clarify your question ...maybe showing us what you expect ... by the way, mind to reset margin to 0 for body ..

Comment: Thanks thats what I was looking for! :D

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you end result should look like, but if you need to specify a width of a container, why dont you use div instead. Here is your updated example:

https://jsfiddle.net/6wfbohbh/8/

```html
<div style="height:1000px; background:lightblue">
<table style="background:lightgreen">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>English</td>
      <td>Spanish</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr style="height: 50px;">
      <td>Hello</td>
      <td>Hola</td>
    </tr>
     <tr style="height: 50px;">
      <td>Bye</td>
      <td>Adios</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```